# Error on running a pl/sql program to find sum of first 10 prime numbers

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
    COUNT   NUMBER;
    prime   NUMBER;
    SUM     NUMBER;
    i       NUMBER;
    j       NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SUM := 2;
    COUNT := 0;
    prime := 1;
    i := 3;

    WHILE COUNT < 10
    LOOP
        j := i / 2;

        FOR k IN 2 .. j
        LOOP
            IF i MOD j = 0
            THEN
                prime := 0;
            END IF;

            IF prime = 1
            THEN
                SUM := SUM + i;
                COUNT := COUNT + 1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SUM);
END;
/
```

I'm trying to calculate the sum first 10 prime numbers. I wrote the above code but when I try to execute it, it throws an error:

> ORA-06550: line 29, column 12:
>  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "+" when expecting one of the following:    ( This error corresponds
>   to the line where I'm incrementing the value of sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` and `SUM` are reserved keywords and must not be choosen as variable-names.

Add a prefix "v":

```
DECLARE
    vCOUNT   NUMBER;
    prime   NUMBER;
    vSUM     NUMBER;
    i       NUMBER;
    j       NUMBER;
BEGIN
    vSUM := 2;
    vCOUNT := 0;
    prime := 1;
    i := 3;

    WHILE vCOUNT < 10
    LOOP
        j := i / 2;

        FOR k IN 2 .. j
        LOOP
            IF i MOD j = 0
            THEN
                prime := 0;
            END IF;

            IF prime = 1
            THEN
                vSUM := vSUM + i;
                vCOUNT := vCOUNT + 1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vSUM);
END;
/
```

Here a good article about naming-conventions in plsql:
https://www.guru99.com/pl-sql-identifiers.html

The error-message "expecting '('" shows that your db wants something like "SUM(someValue)".
An example would be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) FROM mytable
```